# Why is e.parameter.source undefined?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to find out where a callback function came from, but `e.parameter.source` has been undefined.

The code I'me using to create the callback event is:

```
var temp_handler = app.createServerHandler("do_things");
container.add(app.createButton(s_list[i][2]).setId("goto_"+s_list[i][1]).addClickHandler(temp_handler));
container.add(app.createLabel("goto_"+s_list[i][1]));
```

where `container` is later added to the app.

The first part of the function that gets called is:

```
function do_things (e)
{
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  Logger.log(e.parameter);
  var src = e.parameter.source;
```

From this, I have been able to tell that `e.parameter` is:

```
{clientY=61, clientX=38, button=1, alt=false, eventType=click, screenY=278, ctrl=false, screenX=493, y=11, shift=false, meta=false, x=34}
```

This does not include `source`. I find this peculiar because as far as I can tell, other callback functions in the same file have been able to access and use `e.parameter.source` without issue.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong in this callback such that the source parameter is inaccessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers do not make much sense to me.

First, because the `source` parameter is filled by the element `id` that generated the event, not its `name`.

Also it's filled automatically, there's no need to `addCallbackElement`, which is required for accessing widgets contents by their `name`. And last, set a `name` for a `label` is only useful when you're setting a tag on it, as there's no "content" for a label.

All that said, the only problem I can imagine is if you're setting the same `id` on another widget and it's messing with your original one (the button). But I haven't tested that to be sure.

Comment: You're right as usual, I misunderstood the question, sorry about that... I guess the other answerer (Srik) was mislead by my answer as well :-/  mea culpa

Comment: This was in fact the problem - that there were multiple ids that were the same which somehow meant that no source was passed in the parameters to the callback function. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You simply forgot to give a name to your Label widget.  The value returned by the e.parameter is assigned to a widget by its **name**.

The ID is used to access the widget from outside the UiApp creation function when you need to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Serge answered, you might want to supply a callback element on the handler using

```
 ServerHandler.addCallbackElement()
```